# jQuery Cycle 2 Pager not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I have a jQuery Cycle slider on [this page](http://opteracreative.com/~mmceda/) and while the slider works perfectly the pager does not show up as it [should](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/pager.php)

Here is the code for the slider:

```
<div id="slider" class="cycle-slideshow 
data-cycle-fx="fade" 
data-cycle-timeout="4000"
data-cycle-slides="> div">

<div class="slide">
<img src="http://192.254.149.221/~mmceda/images/plane_slider.jpg" alt="map" width="926" height="219" >
<div class="slide-info">
<h5>Our Assets...</h5>
<div class="short-black-line"></div>
<h6>Your Industries</h6>
<p>Monroeville’s pro-business environment continues to attract industry sectors for which it has special assets.</p>
<p><a class="read-more" href="./finance-incentives/">Read More &raquo;</a></p>
</div><!-- end .slide-info -->
</div><!-- end .slide -->


<div class="slide">
<img src="http://192.254.149.221/~mmceda/images/train_tracks.jpg" alt="map" width="926" height="219" >
<div class="slide-info">
<h5>Our Assets...</h5>
<div class="short-black-line"></div>
<h6>Your Industries</h6>
<p>Monroeville’s pro-business environment continues to attract industry sectors for which it has special assets.</p>
<p><a class="read-more" href="./finance-incentives/">Read More &raquo;</a></p>
</div><!-- end .slide-info -->
</div><!-- end .slide -->


<div class="slide">
<img src="http://192.254.149.221/~mmceda/images/welding.jpg" alt="map" width="926" height="219" >
<div class="slide-info">
<h5>Discover</h5>
<div class="short-black-line"></div>
<h6>Our Targets</h6>
<p>Monroeville’s pro-business environment continues to attract industry sectors for which it has special assets.</p>
<p><a class="read-more" href="./discover-monroeville/discover-our-industry-targets-working-title/">Read More &raquo;</a></p>
</div><!-- end .slide-info -->
</div><!-- end .slide --> 
</div>
```

Here is the generated code for the pager:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 92; visibility: hidden;" class="cycle-pager cycle-slide"><span class="cycle-pager-active">•</span><span>•</span><span>•</span><span>•</span><span>•</span><span>•</span><span>•</span><span>•</span></div>
```

I have also set styling for the elements in css, but they don't appear to stick.

```
/* pager */
.cycle-pager { 
    text-align: center; 
    width: 100%; 
    z-index: 10000; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 10px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.cycle-pager span { 
    font-family: arial; 
    font-size: 50px; 
    width: 20px; 
    height: 20px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    color: #797979; 
    cursor: pointer; 
}
.cycle-pager span.cycle-pager-active { color: #82151a;}
.cycle-pager > * { cursor: pointer;}
```

I would appreciate some guidance to know how to get the pagers to show up.

Comment: I'd be guessing here :P but I reckon its got perhaps something maye oughta kinda to do with `style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 92;` **visibility: hidden;"**

Comment: That would be my guess as well, however, that is what the code generates. I have attempted to override it in the CSS. Also, if you look at the code inspector, they are visible.

Comment: Ah ok, if it's generated the it's probably should be that way.  I can't see you actually instantiating a blank div `<div class="cycle-pager"></div>` in your other HTML?

Comment: Looking at this, there are all the tips you need http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/pager.php

Comment: Rob, I have been over that page again and again. The reason I am here is because the code from that page is not working correctly.

Comment: Maybe your opening tag needs fixing first? `<div id="slider" class="cycle-slideshow 
data-cycle-fx="fade" 
data-cycle-timeout="4000"
data-cycle-slides=">` **div">**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah buddy,
just malformed HTML by the looks of things.

Your opening tag of:

```
<div id="slider" class="cycle-slideshow 
data-cycle-fx="fade" 
data-cycle-timeout="4000"
data-cycle-slides="> div">
```

Should be:

```
<div id="slider" class="cycle-slideshow 
data-cycle-fx="fade" 
data-cycle-timeout="4000"
data-cycle-slides=".slide">
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/9nY3L/

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for the help and for sticking with me. I am making a note of this for future reference.

Comment: @fmz Glad it's sorted, however don't think you really need to make a note to check your malformed HTML in the future! But hey-ho, each to their own I guess!

Comment: If you look at the documentation for non-image sliders, it actually uses that "> div"> Go figure.

Comment: @fmz, Ah yes, I see.  That means target all child `div`s in the `.cycle-slideshow` `div` hence in your instance you were giving them a class of `slide` hence `data-cycle-slides=".slide"` using the jQuery selector syntax.

Comment: See why I wanted to make a note of it. Thanks again.

Comment: @fmz Yes I can see that now! Seemed like malformed html to me!